# Find Error in the vertex of a fitted parabola

Tags: error, fitting, curve-fitting, error-propagation

I have a set of data (a Cross-Correlation function) to which I've adjusted a parabola (using [lmfit python package](https://lmfit-py.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/intro.html) ), from the fit I got the values of the parameters and their error:

- (Model): $f(x; a, b, c) = a x^2 + b x + c $

  $ a \pm \delta a$

  $ b \pm \delta b$

  $ c \pm \delta c$

the only thing I'm interested with the fit is the **position of the vertex** of the parabola, but I need to have a measure of the **error** of such position... and I'm unsure of how to obtain it.

Initialy I thought that since the vertex position is defined by $v=\frac{-b}{2a}$ I just need to use the standard error propagation formula $\delta v = |\frac{\partial v}{\partial a}|\delta a +|\frac{\partial v}{\partial b}|\delta b $ but I'm unsure the at is the correct approach... 
Any help will be most appreciated! Thanks

[image: Example of the data I have and the fitted portion]

Comment: I have a hunch that the multivariate delta method could be useful here, applied to the two estimators $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ you have for true coefficients $a$ and $b$. The tricky part is going to be the fact that $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ are correlated in a specific way because they follow from linear regression. However, if you have a lot of data points, you could just ignore that correlation.

Comment: How did you do the fitting?  Is your procedure capable of reporting the full covariance matrix of the three estimated parameters?  (It's likely those estimates are strongly correlated, so this matters.)

Comment: First thanks for the responses. 
For the fitting I use a Non-Linear Least-Squares Fitting algorithm in python called lmfit. But the fit in itself is not problematic, what I need is an error in the position of the vertex assuming that the errors in the parameters $a$ and $b$ are ok.
Indeed both are correlated and regarding the data points I'm fitting several hundreds (or thousands) in that red window.
could you please link me something regarding multivariate delta method? I don't know anything about it...

Comment: The multivariate delta method requires either you assume the estimates are uncorrelated or that you have the full covariance matrix.  Whether or not the fit is problematic and regardless of how much data you have, it's likely the correlations of your estimates are large, so for many applications it would be wise to pursue a solution that estimates and exploits those covariances.

Comment: I have the covariance matrix, is one of the outputs of the lmfit is something like this:

 `[[ 7.65966830e-13 -4.62643967e-11  5.77334733e-11]
 [-4.62643967e-11  3.30705058e-09 -1.89700683e-08]
 [ 5.77334733e-11 -1.89700683e-08  9.00880263e-07]]`

and the correlations of my variables is also indeed large, for the example of the matrix above are:

`[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(a, b) = -0.919
    C(b, c) = -0.348`

Comment: My remark above that "if you have a lot of data points, you could just ignore that correlation" is wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is not the right approach, because the usual regression models don't apply to a cross-correlation function, which means your estimated covariance matrix will be (perhaps grossly) incorrect.  You ought to base your analysis on the underlying time series data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use Stan (https://mc-stan.org/), you can build your statistical model and infer the parameters by sampling: i.e. stan can sample from the posterior distribution of the parameters. Having samples, you can calculate estimates of the mean and standard deviation of your model parameters.

**It can be a little trickier to get Stan to work**. Below I present my code using python and pystan.

For the Stan model, it is crucial to have prior distribution. Therefore, by any preferred method (e.g. maximum likelihood) I get prior guesses of the parameters `a_prior`, `b_prior`, `p_prior`. Then I assume that prior distribution is gaussian around these means with e.g. 30% std (`error_precentage=0.3`). The model that I'm fitting is:

```
a ~ normal(a_prior, square(a_prior*error_precentage));
b ~ normal(b_prior, square(b_prior*error_precentage));
p ~ normal(p_prior, square(p_prior*error_precentage));
    
y ~ normal(a-b*square(x-p), square(y_std));
```

Full code:

```py
import pystan

stan_code = """
data {
    int N;
    vector[N] y;
    vector[N] x;
    real y_std;
    real a_prior;
    real b_prior;
    real p_prior;
    real error_precentage;
}
transformed data {
    
}
parameters {
    real a;
    real b;
    real p;
}
transformed parameters {
}
model {
    a ~ normal(a_prior, square(a_prior*error_precentage));
    b ~ normal(b_prior, square(b_prior*error_precentage));
    p ~ normal(p_prior, square(p_prior*error_precentage));
    
    y ~ normal(a-b*square(x-p), square(y_std));
}
generated quantities {
}
"""

fit = sm.sampling(data={"N":len(temp), "x":x, "y":y, "y_std":y.std(), 
                        "a_prior":a_prior, "b_prior":b_prior, 
                        "p_prior":p_prior, "error_precentage":error_precentage},
                        iter=5000, chains=8, 
                        )
lb = fit.extract(pars=["a", "b", "p"],permuted=False, inc_warmup=False);

# the statistics for the vertex of parabola
np.mean(lb["p"].flatten()), np.std(lb["p"].flatten())
```